# Puma log config -- 200 OK going to STDERR

Tags: ruby, puma

My pumaconf.rb has this line:

```
stdout_redirect '/var/log/puma/puma.log', '/var/log/puma/puma-err.log', true
```

puma.log contains:

```
=== puma startup: 2016-09-07 23:33:01 +0000 === [4433] - Worker 0 (pid: 4436) booted, phase: 0
```

puma-err.log contains:

```
10.10.10.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:00:03:27 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0005 
10.10.10.1 - - [08/Sep/2016:00:03:27 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0005
```

Any tips on what I may have incorrectly setup?

**Edit:**

A little more info on my side -- I set up a new test in a clone of the puma code, with the following config:

```
log_requests
stdout_redirect "t4-stdout", "t4-stderr", true
pidfile "t4-pid"
bind "tcp://0.0.0.0:10103"
rackup File.expand_path('../hello.ru', File.dirname(__FILE__))
daemonize false
```

And wrote a test around "200 OK should only be in stdout, not in stderr" and everything is passing.

I'm pretty stumped why spinning up a puma server from the base repo is acting so differently, but I will keep digging.

Comment: why do you think something is incorrectly set up

Comment: Why would 200 OK go to my stderr file, and not stdout?